# Register Custom Action with Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-on-prem, custom-actions, custom-list-actions

I am having difficulty registering a custom user action through JavaScript. I am using the following code example. The code executes without any error however the button fails to appear on the Ribbon. I am hoping someone maybe able to point out where I have gone wrong

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var userCustomActionColl = oList.get_userCustomActions();

clientContext.load(oList, 'UserCustomActions', 'Title');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync();

var oUserCustomAction = userCustomActionColl.add();
oUserCustomAction.set_location('CommandUI.Ribbon.EditForm');
oUserCustomAction.set_sequence(1);
oUserCustomAction.set_title("Related Items -" + fieldDisplayName);
var uiExtension = '<CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">' +
            '<CommandUIDefinitions>' +
                '<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.Controls._children">'+
                    '<Button Id="RibbonTest2" '+
                            'Command="TestCommand" '+
                            'Sequence="0" '+
                            'Image16by16="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_16x16.png" '+
                            'Image32by32="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_32x32.png" '+
                            'Description="Uses the notification area to display a message." '+
                            'LabelText="Notify hello" '+
                            'TemplateAlias="o1"/>' +
                '</CommandUIDefinition>'+
            '</CommandUIDefinitions>'+
            '<CommandUIHandlers>'+
                '<CommandUIHandler Command="TestCommand" '+
                    'CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(\'Hello from the notification area\');" />'+
            '</CommandUIHandlers>'+
           '</CommandUIExtension>';

oUserCustomAction.set_commandUIExtension(uiExtension);
oUserCustomAction.set_registrationId(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
oUserCustomAction.set_registrationType(1);
oUserCustomAction.update();
clientContext.load(userCustomActionColl);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync();
```

Comment: Please check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213552/how-do-you-create-custom-actions-in-2016) and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-ribbon-custom-action-using-javascript-object-model-in-sharepoint-2016-and/). Also you can do this with the help of PowerShell as given [here](https://olafd.wordpress.com/2017/01/26/sharepoint-ribbon-scripts-with-external-javascript-files/).

Comment: Also there are some examples in Microsoft documentation, [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185004(v%3Doffice.14)).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. What i am actually trying to do is target lists that have a custom field type. I use CSR to render the field (Its a custom picker) and dynamically add the custom actions if they do not exist. I have other custom action being added (List Item Menu), and these work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parking it for a few days i have managed to get it working by removing the following calls:-

- set_location
- set_registrationId
- set_registrationType
- set_sequence

I have also removed the icon references because they were invalid.